# java: incompatible types: inference variable RR has incompatible bounds

Tags: java, java-stream

jdk 1.8

Set and Collection.

I want to get count of intersection that > 0.

I try this:

```java
SortedSet<VsatVlan> vsatVlans;
Collection<Integer> mobilityNsVlansList = mobilityNS.getVlanIds();
....
long intersectionCount = vsatVlans.stream()
    .filter(vsatVlan -> mobilityNsVlansList.contains(vsatVlan.getVlanId()))
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.toSet(),
        set -> { // error here
            if (set.size() != 1) {
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
            return set.size();
        }
    ));
```

But I get error:

```
incompatible parameter types in lambda expression: expected Set<Object> but found Set<VsatVlan>

java: incompatible types: inference variable RR has incompatible bounds
lower bounds: java.lang.Long,java.lang.Object
lower bounds: java.lang.Integer
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Count how many elements the set has, whose ids appear in the list? If yes, why the `collectingAndThen` ? Shouldn't `stream().filter(...).count()` suffice?

Comment: Make `intersectionCount` an `int`. That seems to throw the whole type inference off.

Comment: @Eritrean I need smt like "stream().filter(...).count() > 0". Is it possible?

Comment: @a_subscriber but that would be a boolean not a long.

Comment: Is this a method? What does it return? Are you trying to return the count of intersection and if the count is 0 throw an exception?

Comment: @Eritrean I need to return count of intersection only if it > 0.

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right you want to return count of intersection only if not zero else you want to throw an exception. You need to explicitly supply the type of the set to get rid of the error you get:

```
return vsatVlans.stream()
                .filter(vsatVlan -> mobilityNsVlansList.contains(vsatVlan.getVlanId()))
                .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toSet(),
                    (Set<VsatVlan> set) -> {
                        if (set.size() == 0) {
                            throw new IllegalStateException("");
                        }
                        return set.size();
                    }
               ));
```

You also could use Optionals here and and avoid the if block:

```
return vsatVlans.stream()
               .filter(vsatVlan -> mobilityNsVlansList.contains(vsatVlan.getVlanId()))
               .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.counting(), Optional::of))
               .filter(x -> x > 0)
               .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException(""));
```

but IMO counting and then checking in a separate if block, is way more readable than the above two:

```
long count = vsatVlans.stream()
                      .filter(vsatVlan -> mobilityNsVlansList.contains(vsatVlan.getVlanId()))
                      .count();
if(count == 0){
    new IllegalStateException("")
}
return count;
```

Comment: It seems to me that the OP wants `distinct().count()`